# Detecting if a browser is in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, fullscreen

Is there any way of reliably detecting if a browser is running in full screen mode? I'm pretty sure there isn't any browser API I can query, but has anyone worked it out by inspecting and comparing certain height/width measurements exposed by the DOM? Even if it only works for certain browsers I'm interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Why do you need to detect this?  Maybe there is another solution to your problem?

Comment: When the browser is in full screen mode there is no way of seeing the time reported by the operating system (e.g. in the clock in the taskbar notification area on Windows). Being able to see the current time can be important for users of our web application, so we'd like to be able to display a clock when the browser is full screened. Screen real estate is at a premium when our application is run at lower resolutions like 1024*768 so we'd like to only display the clock when the browser is full screened if at all possible.

Comment: What if they don't normally have a clock on their desktop, and also don't use their browser full-screened? Are you sure you are the one responsible for them knowing the current time?

Comment: Our desire to do this is based on customer feedback.

Comment: I don't understand the third degree questioning of the motive here.  There are a number of reasons why a web application (for instance) maybe should look/behave differently in F11 mode than in regular chrome.  Focus on providing a solution rather than questioning intent.

Answer (score 16):

Chrome 15, Firefox 10, and Safari 5.1 now provide APIs to programmatically trigger fullscreen mode. Fullscreen mode triggered this way provides events to detect fullscreen changes and CSS pseudo-classes for styling fullscreen elements.

See [this hacks.mozilla.org blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/) for details.

Comment: Still, is there a way to detect user entered full screen using browser provided means (like F11 or menu next to Zoom in Chrome)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement

Answer (score 8):

What about determining the distance between the viewport width and the resolution width and likewise for height. If it is a small amount of pixels (especially for height) it *may* be at fullscreen.

However, this will never be reliable.

Comment: If the browser is actually running fullscreen, the difference between the viewport size and the resolution should equal 0. Unless you're running multiple monitors, i guess.

Comment: Are scrollbars counted as part of the viewport?

Comment: I'm not sure - you'll have to experiment.

Comment: This was the lines I was thinking along. I could write a test page which displays all the dimensions of interest and compare the dimensions reported for the page when displayed normally and full screen. From there I *might* be able to determine the state for certain browsers.

Comment: Maybe something like if (resolutionHeight - viewportHeight) < 100) = fullscreen = true

Comment: Just tested with Chrome. `window.innerWidth` , `document.body.clientWidth` , `document.width`  and `document.documentElement.clientWidth` all report the same value ...

Answer (score 8):

Opera treats full screen as a different CSS media type. They call it [Opera Show](http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/operashow/), and you can control it yourself easily:

```
@media projection {
  /* these rules only apply in full screen mode */
}
```

Combined with [Opera@USB](http://www.opera-usb.com/), I've personally found it extremely handy.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - how is this related to Javascript?

Answer (score 8):

You can check if `document.fullscreenElement` is not null to determine if fullscreen mode is on. You'll need to vendor prefix `fullscreenElement` accordingly. I would use something like this:

```
var fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement ||
document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn312066(v=vs.85).aspx has a good example for this which I quote below:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenChange", function () {
          if (fullscreenElement != null) {
              console.info("Went full screen");
          } else {
              console.info("Exited full screen");              
          }
      });
```

Comment: Other solutions are sub-standart if this one works.

Answer (score 6):

The Document read-only property returns the Element that is currently being presented in full-screen mode in this document, or null if full-screen mode is not currently in use.

```
if(document.fullscreenElement){
  console.log("Fullscreen");
}else{
  console.log("Not Fullscreen");
};
```

Supports in all major browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox 3+ provides a non-standard property on the `window` object that reports whether the browser is in full screen mode or not: [`window.fullScreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.fullScreen).

Comment: Nice! This does work reliably in Firefox. This is definitely a piece of the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Just thought I'd add my thruppence to save anyone banging their heads. The first answer is excellent if you have complete control over the process, that is you initiate the fullscreen process in code. Useless should anyone do it thissen by hitting F11.

The glimmer of hope on the horizon come in the form of this W3C recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/view-mode/ which will enable detection of windowed, floating (without chrome), maximized, minimized and fullscreen via media queries (which of course means window.matchMedia and associated).

I've seen signs that it's in the implementation process with -webkit and -moz prefixes but it doesn't appear to be in production yet.

So no, no solutions but hopefully I'll save someone doing a lot of running around before hitting the same wall.

PS *:-moz-full-screen does doo-dah as well, but nice to know about.

Comment: The linked recommendation is obsolete as of October 2018 and won't be implemented, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

While searching high & low I have found only half-solutions.
So it's better to post here a modern, working approach to this issue:

```
var isAtMaxWidth = (screen.availWidth - window.innerWidth) === 0;
var isAtMaxHeight = (screen.availHeight - window.outerHeight <= 1);
if (!isAtMaxWidth || !isAtMaxHeight) {
       alert("Browser NOT maximized!");
}
```

Tested and working properly in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera* (*with Sidebar unpinned) as of 10.11.2019.
Testing environment (only desktop):

```
CHROME - Ver. 78.0.3904.97 (64-bit)
FIREFOX - Ver. 70.0.1 (64-bit)
EDGE - Ver. 44.18362.449.0 (64-bit)
OPERA - Ver. 64.0.3417.92 (64-bit)
OS - WIN10 build 18362.449 (64-bit)
```

Resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/availWidth
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/availHeight
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerHeight

Answer (score 3):

For Safari on iOS can use:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
  alert("Full Screen");
}
```

More:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome at least:

`onkeydown` can be used to detect the F11 key being pressed to enter fullscreen.
`onkeyup` can be used to detect the F11 key being pressed to exit fullscreen.

Use that in conjunction with checking for `keyCode == 122`

The tricky part would be to tell the keydown/keyup not to execute its code if the other one just did.

Comment: This doesn't help if the user entered fullscreen with F11 before they navigated to the web page running that javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Right. Totally late on this one...

As of 25th Nov, 2014 (Time of writing), it is possible for elements to request fullscreen access, and subsequently control entering/exiting fullscreen mode.

MDN Explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Straightforward explanation by David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

This works for all new browsers :

```
if (!window.screenTop && !window.screenY) { 
   alert('Browser is in fullscreen');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this test has turned unreliable.

Comment: This seems to work:                                                   if (screen.height === window.outerHeight) { 
   alert('Browser is in fullscreen');
}

Comment: No, the second solution doesn't work in Chrome 23, when Fullscreen via API is on, but the user turns it off with Ctrl+alt+F.

Comment: @TomUlatowski - could you be more specific when it turned unreliable?

Comment: This won't work if a user has no window borders and has the browser maximized.

Answer (score 1):

There is my NOT cross-browser variant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fullscreen</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fullscreen = $(window).height() + 1 >= screen.height;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if (!fullscreen) {
    setTimeout(function(heightStamp) {
      if (!fullscreen && $(window).height() === heightStamp && heightStamp + 1 >= screen.height) {
        fullscreen = true;
        $('body').prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).height() + " | " + screen.height + " | fullscreen ON</div>" );
      }
    }, 500, $(window).height());
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(heightStamp) {
      if (fullscreen && $(window).height() === heightStamp && heightStamp + 1 < screen.height) {
        fullscreen = false;
        $('body').prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).height() + " | " + screen.height + " | fullscreen OFF</div>" );
      }
    }, 500, $(window).height());
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on:
**Kubuntu 13.10**:
  Firefox 27 (`<!DOCTYPE html>` is required, script correctly works with dual-monitors), Chrome 33, Rekonq - pass

**Win 7**:
  Firefox 27, Chrome 33, Opera 12, Opera 20, IE 10 - pass
  IE < 10 - fail

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
var fullscreenCount = 0;
var changeHandler = function() {                                           

    fullscreenCount ++;

    if(fullscreenCount % 2 === 0)
    {
        console.log('fullscreen exit');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('fullscreened');
    }

}                                                                         
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);      
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChanges", changeHandler, false);
```

Comment: This is a cool solution, but it doesn't seem to support when I press ```f11``` :)
Maybe you could improve it by adding a ```keypress === "f11"``` event or something? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I've come to...
I wrote it as an es6 module but the code should be pretty straightforward.

```
/**
 * Created by sam on 9/9/16.
 */
import $ from "jquery"

function isFullScreenWebkit(){
    return $("*:-webkit-full-screen").length > 0;
}
function isFullScreenMozilla(){
    return $("*:-moz-full-screen").length > 0;
}
function isFullScreenMicrosoft(){
    return $("*:-ms-fullscreen").length > 0;
}

function isFullScreen(){
    // Fastist way
    var result =
        document.fullscreenElement ||
        document.mozFullScreenElement ||
        document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
        document.msFullscreenElement;

    if(result) return true;

    // A fallback
    try{
        return isFullScreenMicrosoft();
    }catch(ex){}
    try{
        return isFullScreenMozilla();
    }catch(ex){}
    try{
        return isFullScreenWebkit();
    }catch(ex){}

    console.log("This browser is not supported, sorry!");
    return false;
}

window.isFullScreen = isFullScreen;

export default isFullScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

2021, the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) is available. It's a Living Standard and is supported by all browsers (except the usual suspects - IE11 and iOS Safari).

```
// toggle fullscreen

      if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        // enter fullscreen
        if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
          console.log('entering fullscreen')
          docElm.requestFullscreen()
        }
      } else {
        // exit fullscreen
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          console.log('exiting fullscreen')
          document.exitFullscreen()
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me tested on at least Chrome and Firefox:

```
const isFullscreen = (window.innerHeight == screen.height) || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen || window.navigator.standalone || (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement != null) || (document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen) || (!window.screenTop && !window.screenY);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

User `window.innerHeight` and `screen.availHeight`. Also the widths.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (window.outerWidth === screen.availWidth && window.outerHeight === screen.availHeight) {
        console.log("This is your MOMENT of fullscreen: " + Date());    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect whether browser is in fullscreen mode:

```
document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement
```

according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen) you should be fine for majority of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This property returns the Element that is currently in fullscreen mode.

```
document.fullscreenElement; // HTML Element or null
```

Also, you can subscribe to fullscreen change events with this method

```
addEventListener('fullscreenchange', (event) => { });
```

You can combine both to detect the nature of the change

```
addEventListener('fullscreenchange', () => { 
 if (document.fullscreenElement) {
   // Your Logic if fullscreen
 }
});
```

More on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

Answer (score 0):

You can detect full screen using CSS like this:

```
@media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
  // Regular CSS to be applied in full-screen mode
}
```