# Javascript: webkitIsFullScreen property IE equivalent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webkit, fullscreen

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation, Internet Explorer does not support something like `webkitIsFullScreen` or like `mozFullScreen` property. I need to read if browser is in full screen mode. Is there any way to get it on IE somehow?
THANKS!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect fullscreen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755129/detect-fullscreen-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using IE11, an equivalent check would be:

```
document.msFullscreenElement !== null
```

Disclosure: I am on the team that worked on Microsoft's implementation of the Fullscreen API.

Comment: Does document.msFullscreenElement returns true on Windows Phones or only Desktop mode?

Comment: This answer should be changed to "!=" instead of the specified "!==", because it is likely msFullscreenElement will be 'undefined'... which breaks this code.

Comment: DAG is almost right. The code won't generate an error. Worse than that, it will generate a false positive. His solution is right on the button though.