# Detecting fullscreenchange does not work on some android devices

Tags: javascript, android

I am currently trying to use the `<video>` tag to, obviously, display videos. If the user clicks on the video (or poster image) it will trigger my script to set the video to fullscreen through the `requestFullScreen` method. When I exit fullscreen mode, I attempt to catch this by using a listener like so:

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function() {
    // This is never triggered, I never arrive here.
    if (isFullScreen) { // do something}
    else { // do something else}
}
```

I have similar listeners for `mozfullscreenchange`, `msfullscreenchange` and `webkitfullscreenchange`.

Now my problem is that for some android devices with some browsers, the listener is not triggered. For instance, on a Samsung Galaxy Note the listener is not triggered when using Chrome, while when using Asus Transformer with Chrome it works. However, if I use Firefox on the same two devices, it only works on Samsung Galaxy Note and not the Asus Transformer.

Is there a simple explanation to this inconsistency? Have I done something wrong? Is there perhaps some different events I should listen to on different versions of Android and browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect fullscreen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755129/detect-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: True. How could I have missed that one :p. Will see if this solves my problem.

Comment: Depending on your needs. But you might want to consider using a JS player to help you with these issues. for example videojs.com

Comment: I have a rather strict restriction to the use of plugins, sadly. I couldn't get it to work so I guess I'm forced to provide a fallback for browsers+devices which do not have the desired events. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the last outter right parenthesis.
Also two curly brackets are commented away.

Comment: Upvoting because this is the solution (though I don't see the 2 commented curly brackets). Still upvoting the question because there's still a problem somewhere else. I'm using a Galaxy S9+, and Chrome throws the event, but Firefox doesn't.

Comment: The missing curly brackets hide in the comments... { // do something} should be { /* do something */ }

Comment: And... I counted 3 of '(' and 2 of ')'. It should always count the same.

Comment: Yes... not sure why I put that in my comment.

Comment: I edited it now.. hope you can see there are /* ... */. It may take a while to peer review. My post may be irrelevant and removed, if it is okay for you.