# IE full Screen mode using selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, fullscreen

I want to check if Internet Explorer window is in fullscreen mode or not?

I use `driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`

It maximizes window only but does not switched to FullScreen view.

Is there any method?

Comment: What do you mean by Full Screen, is it what you get after pressing 'F 11'.?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: How about [using JavaScript to dected whether in fullscreen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755129/detect-fullscreen-mode) and [calling this JavaScript method from your Selenium code](http://www.mkyong.com/selenium/how-to-execute-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver/)?

Comment: @UweKeim: sounds like a good Idea !!! thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Selenium web driver do not have the API to achieve the Full screen as per your post. But you can achieve it through send keys method of windows. Try below code.

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{F11}");
```

Comment: What if InternetExplorer opens in FullScreen? then this command will do the reverse.

Comment: That needs to be decided by you, to where to put that code. Also, there is an option `InternetExplorerOptions` of passing to IE constructor.

Answer (score 0):

@Sham: that is a unique way to do it... I would recommend this:

```
driver.Manage().Window().Maximize(); after window braces should be added
```