# Chrome not detecting fullscreen change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen

I am trying to remove a class from an element when the user presses escape and exits full screen on chrome. My code:

```
document.addEventListener('onwebkitfullscreenchange', 

  function(e)
  {
    console.log("sanity check")
    if ($('#someDiv').hasClass('aClass'))
    {
      $('#someDiv').removeClass('aClass');
    }
  }
);
```

What am I missing here? I never see the "sanity check" output either. Nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755129/detect-fullscreen-mode

Comment: You don't use an `on` prefix with addEventListener - that should be just `webkitfullscreenchange`.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked in F11 mode.

```
    if( window.innerHeight == screen.height) {
    console.log("sanity check")
    }
```

It only works in FullScreen mode.

When I typed, I didn't see @dxcorzo's comment, sorry. It just links to same answer. Credit goes to @dxcorzo :)