# Detect fullscreen mode on mobile

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I had lost much time to search for detecting fullscreen mode on mobile. 
But the result I find out is only for browser desktop. Here 
[Detect fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755129/detect-fullscreen-mode)

Is there any way to detect fullscreen mode on mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `document.fullscreenElement` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement

> This example presents a function, isVideoInFullscreen(), which looks at the value returned by fullscreenElement; if the document is in full-screen mode (fullscreenElement isn't null) and the full-screen element's nodeName is VIDEO, indicating a  element, the function returns true, indicating that the video is in full-screen mode.

```
function isVideoInFullscreen() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement.nodeName == 'VIDEO') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```