# Chrome Notification on fullscreen / game

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem and I cannot find any answers to my questions

1. I have a question, is it possible to show notifications on fullscreen and in game? (Notification priority doesn't work)
2. If the answer to the first question is impossible could I check if the user is in game or on fullscreen?

   ```
    function sendNotificationx(t, b, i, link) {
        var notification = new Notification(t, {
            body: b,
            icon: i,
        });
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Talking about notification, it probably depends how you will make it a screen overlay for the full screen if that's your target, however if you mean by a "notification" like the one that's found on the notification bar, you can't. That's the least that i know of.

```
There's a way particularly for firefox. 
The Document interface provides properties that can be used to determine if full-screen mode is supported and available, and if full-screen mode is currently active, which element is using the screen.

if((window.fullScreen) ||
    (window.innerWidth == 
    screen.width 
    && window.innerHeight == 
     screen.height)) {

    } else {

  }

Document.fullscreenElement / ShadowRoot.fullscreenElement
The fullscreenElement property tells you the Element that's currently being displayed in full-screen mode on the DOM (or shadow DOM). If this is null, the document (or shadow DOM) is not in full-screen mode.

document.fullscreenEnabled
The fullscreenEnabled property tells you whether or not it is possible to engage full-screen mode. This is false if full-screen mode is not available for any reason (such as the "fullscreen" feature not being allowed, or full-screen mode not being supported).
```

As well as let's say, it depends on the target platform your going to use.

Opera has 'Opera Show',

On the other hand you can use css Media queries - once the specific media query has been activated or matched as the full screen media query, you can call that a deal.

Mind as well check on [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047319/detecting-if-a-browser-is-in-full-screen-mode)
Anytime soon, this post might be tagged as duplicate.

Comment: thanks its for fullscreen, do you have some idea with game?